# I was unable to solve this mechanics/physics exercise and I can't find anything close to have a base

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image: Mass in G = 500 kg. What's the force in AD? (1 ft = 0,3048 m)]

Mass in G = 500 kg. What's the force in AD? (1 ft = 0,3048 m)

For me, there's not enough information. I don't have all the coordinates or angles to do a complete free body diagram and I'm not sure what to do without them. The other exercises I did had, in my mind, enough information. It goes further than only the force in AD, but my problem is only this part of the exercise.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would be assuming that AD is exactly horizontal.  In that case I believe there is enough information.

I am not doing any math, just looking at the diagram, but I would find the torque of the load about E, which gives you the force in AC.  From there you just have to contemplate the forces at A.

Comment: The diagram is giving you a hint about where to look by labeling some pins with letters and leaving others unlabeled.

Comment: I have already tried finding the torque in E. However, since C is in a different coordinate in both X and Y axes, I will end up with a torque relation between these two variables, because both axes will generate torque. And I couldn't find another equation to solve it.

Comment: I would find the length EC and the angle ACE.  This allows you to find the force in AC directly without making a mess of x and y components or whatever is confusing you.

Comment: I could find EC and ACE. But I can't find GE or GC to calculate the torque this load is applying. All was given was the distance between GE and GC, but only in the x axis. I have neither distances in y axis or any angle to calculate them.

Comment: Is the torque exerted by AC about E equal to 0.25 ft*(force AC)?  No.  It is the result of a cross product.  If that doesn’t make sense, just review your procedure for computing torque.  You should take angles into account somewhere.  Trigonometry May be necessary.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. My problem is to calculate the distance between GE or GC to calculate the load G is doing in E. I only have one of the necessary distances, because, as you stated, the torque is the result of a cross product.

Comment: And you do know that the vertical distance between C and E is 1 ft

Comment: Yes, but not the vertical distance between G and C nor G and E. But I need one of these distances to calculate the torque G is doing, right?

Comment: No, the direction of the load’s weight is straight down, so you only need the horizontal distance from the axis to compute the torque.

Comment: If you wish, you may verify this by plugging in X as your missing distance.  You will find it cancels out and you get a numerical answer.

Comment: Oh, Ok then. I didn't know that. I'll do it with this information. Thanks a lot for the explanation and patience. It was very helpful.

Comment: No problem.  Don’t forget to accept my answer if your question is resolved.